# What is the type of art work in roadrash game called?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, character-design

I have been fascinated by RoadRash artwork all my life , but I seem to not understand it and how to go about it

[image: Road Rash Home]

[image: Characters]

How are they able to make such posterized characters!
Why this kind of artwork stopped?

Comment: How is this a graphic design question?

Comment: I was wondering if these characters were possible to design

Comment: Look up "how to draw Caricatures".  This is not called "RoadRash artwork". Also some of these are not drawings, but probably photomanipulation work.

Comment: @BillyKerr  those are the images I get when I google that word

Comment: RoadRash is the name of a video game.  Obviously you will get images from the game if you google it.  But the style of Illustration is called "caricature".

Comment: @BillyKerr yes, I, first of all, didn't know it was a caricature. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style is a very old one - known as [Caricature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caricature)

The essence is to exaggerate features whilst still maintaining recognition of the character being caricatured.

It is normally done as a drawing process rather than computer-generated, but it can be faked using something like Liquify in Photoshop.
The best caricatures take a known figure & exaggerate parts that are perceived as deviating from the norm. Otherwise, simply forcing the perspective, as in your second example, is relatively easy & doesn't require the person to be already recognisable.

Comment: so you are telling me all those characters were real people?

Comment: Your 2nd image looks like manipulated photographs, so yes. The 1st is harder to tell, but they look drawn, to me.